# individuality usage as set phrase/expression

Tags: grammar, expressions

Let's say you want to express something using a common expression, is this sentence correct?

> I don't want to emulate others much, because this act does not develop
>   my own individuality.

Note:if you spot any incorrect vocabulary usage, pls. Help. And if you can suggest alternatives or better expression even, feel free to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, although you could also omit "own".

Basically, you can always use Google as the first step in determining whether a certain phrase is in use by native speakers. For example, [googling for "develop my individuality" (in quotation marks)](https://www.google.com/search?q="develop+my+individuality"&ie=utf-8) turns up many results from books by native speakers, including the venerable [G.K.Chesterton](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=GoS4VbKr90cC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=%22develop+my+individuality%22&source=bl&ots=GFgzeVxUkI&sig=tpK2T8QXFdAhs70cTqMJiEfRQH8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirgfynkYXZAhVDWiwKHaqYDiYQ6AEIOTAF).

The only other caveat is that it is better to say "emulate others *too* much".

Also, it's best to replace "this act" with "doing so". X+ing is a form called gerund—a verb turned into a noun of sorts. "This act" presupposes one specific act, while you are talking about repeated actions.

Comment: Hello, thx for your feedback. I almost get all what you are saying, but, in terms of emulate, as my verb in present tense form, I don't quite get it why do you have to  change it into 'doing so' from 'this act', because usually ''verb(ing)’s'' are usually grounded only for a temporary action(PLAYING a computer game, WASHING the dishes, and so on) Clearly, not used as facts or in repeated actions. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JohnArvin Your sentence basically says it is your desire to avoid emulating others in general, not just in some specific case. Even if you are talking about a specific action, your sentence expresses your general rule. "This act" sounds a bit pompous and can only refer to 1 specific instance (and only if you've mentioned it in a previous sentence). "Doing so" is a good way to refer to the 1st half of your sentence—it is essentially a replacement for "emulating other people" (you don't need to repeat "emulating" a 2nd time) and it works both for a specific situation and for a general rule.

Comment: @JohnArvin Besides, what you seem to be talking about is the Present Continuous tense ("to be" +ing). I'm not talking about this. I'm talking about a grammatical concept that is probably new to you — [gerund](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gerund) (click on the link for more explanation). Notice how I haven't put "is" or "are" before "doing"; it stands alone. Every verb can be made into a "virtual noun" by adding +ing. For example, "Playing guitar is my favorit pastime"; "Crying will not help you solve the problem".

Comment: I just took a glimpse of the link you put in. I'll review it coz it's too long, I'll get back to you if I have clarifications(would you mind replying again hehe) thx all in all.

Comment: @JohnArvin you could thank me by "accepting" my answer. It gives you +5 reputation, and +15 reputation to the user whose answer you've accepted.

Comment: Hehe you really break down the reputation points aye. Yes, of course, why I shouldn't do that when it is correct. Thx, I'll get back here later.

Comment: Hello again, this is an excerpt from cambridge website regarding 'DOING  SO',  
''The government banned tobacco advertising and, IN doing so (= because of this), contributed greatly to the nation's health'' do you have to change >BECAUSE DOING SO to IN DOING SO. Thx

Comment: From my highlighted sentence above is ''I don't want to emulate others much, because DOING SO does not develop my own individuality.(is this exactly you were saying right?)

Comment: @JohnArvin Yes. "In doing so" could be rephrased using your words "this act" (although I told you it sounded a bit pompous)—"_through_ this act", something like this.

Comment: So it's gonna be 'BECAUSE IN DOING SO' or just 'IN DOING SO?'

Comment: @JohnArvin In your sentence, BECAUSE DOING SO does not develop my individuality". "Doing so" becomes the subject of this clause. Other examples: [1](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=3eQhbVAi4rwC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=%22because%20doing%20so%22&f=false), [2](https://books.google.com.ua/books?redir_esc=y&id=io8kqPe5pDAC&q=%22because+doing+so%22#v=snippet), [3](https://books.google.com.ua/books?redir_esc=y&id=rGfnAgAAQBAJ&q="because+doing+so"#v=snippet)

Comment: Got it! Thx again.